# Send array from javascript to php then write it to file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

i cant seem to get this to work, i'm trying to send a variable to php so it can write it to file but its just not working..

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(vars);
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "woepanel.php",
    data: {data : jsonString}, 
    cache: false,

    success: function(){
        $('#sent').attr("bgcolor", "#00FF00");
        $('#notsent').attr("bgcolor", "#FFFFFF");
    }
});
```

it seems to be sending ok because the success works but php wont pick it up

```
<?php
$vars=json_decode($_POST['jsondata']); 
?>
<?php
$fp = fopen('vars.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $_POST["jsondata"]);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: but you are sending data not jsondata

Comment: `$_POST['jsondata'] to $_POST['data ']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php
$vars=json_decode($_POST['data']);

$string_data = serialize($vars);
file_put_contents('vars.txt', $string_data);
?>
```

Comment: [15-Apr-2014 12:25:30 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Comment: it wont write an array

Answer (score 0):

you have this

data: {data : jsonString}

in your ajax call which means you should use

$_POST['data']

to extract the value

Comment: or maybe just change `data: {data: jsonString}` to be `data: jsonString`